# Understanding a lemma in CO-H-STRUCTURES ON MOORE SPACES OF TYPE(G,2).

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

Here is the lemma and its proof:

> [image]

**My questions are:**

1- Why is $\theta$ an isomorphism?

2- In line 4, why $\tilde{\theta}$ definition contains a $+$ sign?

3- why the condition that $[X, Y \vee Y]$ is abelian required for $\mu$ to be a homomorphism?

4- Why to show that $j_{*}\rho =1,$ it suffices to prove that $j_{*} \mu = \tilde{\theta}$? and how can this be varified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1)$ Because it has an inverse. Namely the map $\tilde\theta$, which we check satisfies $\theta\tilde\theta=1$ and $\tilde\theta\theta=1$.

$2)$ Because if the plus sign is changed to a minus sign, then $\tilde\theta$ is not inverse to $\theta$. Of course if $X$ is not a cogroup, then there is no way to take inverses in the first place.

$3)$ For $\alpha,\alpha',\beta,\beta'\in[X.Y]$ we have
$$\mu[(\beta,\gamma)+(\beta',\gamma')]=\mu(\beta+\beta',\gamma+\gamma')=i_{1*}(\beta+\beta')+i_{2*}(\gamma+\gamma')=i_{1*}\beta+i_{1*}\beta'+i_{2*}\gamma+i_{2*}\gamma'$$ while
$$\mu(\beta,\gamma)+\mu(\beta',\gamma')=i_{1*}\beta+i_{2*}\gamma+i_{1*}\beta'+i_{2*}\gamma'.$$
Note that the middle two terms in the sum are switched, so these expressions are not equal in general. Here I am allowed to neglect brackets due to the assumption that $X$ is associative.

$4)$ By definition $j_*\rho=(j\mu)\theta$. Note that composition of maps and homotopy class is an associative operation. If $j_*\mu=\tilde\theta$, then $j_*\rho=\tilde\theta\theta$, since $\theta,\tilde\theta$ are inverse. Conversely, if $j_*\rho=1$, then $\tilde\theta=1\tilde\theta=(j_*\rho)\tilde\theta=(j\mu\theta)\tilde\theta=(j\mu)(\theta\tilde\theta)=ju$. Thus we have shown that $j_*\mu=\tilde\theta$ if and only if $j_*\rho=1$.